# Wiring a 2-gang light switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I would like to remove an old 2 gang dimmer swtch and replace it with a standard 2 gang switch. My new 2 gang switch is a 2 way switch but I will be using it as a one way switch.

The current wiring has different colours to the current UK standard as it was fitted around 30 years ago.

My new switch has 2 x COM, L1, and L2 connections.

This is my existing switch - can anyone tell me what should be connected to which connections on my new switch please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Wait for an expert, but the red wire with the big bend on the left side should be your power/hot/live wire.  The yellow and the red on the right side are the switched hot wires(only have power with the switch on).  The short blue wire is a jumper carrying power from one switch to the next.  That connection of the red and blue is bad, it should be done with a local proper wire connector(I think you use wagos).  That red should be connected to two short reds to the switches.  The blue in the back should be a neutral, not used for most switches, so leave it.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense - so essentially the left side red is the live in, and the other red and yellow are the out to the lights which get connected when the switch is on? It makes sense if so, but not sure why they would be different colours. Or is that to help differentiate which cable is for which light? And yes, a bad use of the blue cable to jump the live from gang 1 to gang 2.

Comment: One cable is a three wire cable(ground not counted) so they need red, blue and another colour.

Comment: Thanks again. Followed this advice as it seemed to make sense and all seems to have worked perfectly! Much appreciated feedback!